# counting names based on value column pandas

Tags: python, pandas

For the following dataframe, based on colorsnames covered over two plants, looking to create new column that counts 1 if color exists in both plants and 0 if this is not the case:

df:

```
Color      Plant
green1     1
blue2      1
red1       1
purple6    2
blue2      1
blue3      2
green1     2
green1     1
red2       1
purple6    1
```

Desired output:

```
Color      Plant   Spillover
green1     1       1
blue2      1       0
red1       1       0
purple6    2       1
blue2      1       0
blue3      2       0
green1     2       1
green1     1       1
red2       1       0
purple6    1       1
```

Comment: your data seems inconsistent. in the original dataframe blue2 is in plant 1 and 2, however in the output dataframe, blue 2 is associated with 1 twice and has a spillover of 0

Comment: The `Plant` column doesn't match in the input and desired output?

Comment: colors can occur multiple times by multiple rows. So blue 2 occurs 2 times, but only in plant 1 and therefore gets a 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `GroupBy.nunique` to check the amount of unique plants per Color. If these are `> 1`, then there's spillover between the plants:

```
df['Spillover'] = df['Color'].map(df.groupby('Color')['Plant'].nunique()).gt(1).astype(int)

     Color  Plant  Spillover
0   green1      1          1
1    blue2      1          0
2     red1      1          0
3  purple6      2          1
4    blue2      1          0
5    blue3      2          0
6   green1      2          1
7   green1      1          1
8     red2      1          0
9  purple6      1          1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution:

```
df["Spillover"] = df.groupby("Color").transform(lambda x: 1 in list(x) and 2 in list(x)).astype(int)
```

The output is:

```
     Color  Plant  Spillover
0   green1      1          1
1    blue2      1          1
2     red1      1          0
3  purple6      2          1
4    blue2      2          1
5    blue3      2          0
6   green1      2          1
7   green1      1          1
8     red2      1          0
9  purple6      1          1
```

If you have multiple plants and don't like the 'and' part of the if statement, you can do:

```
s = set([1,2]) # list of relevant plants
df["Spillover"] = df.groupby("Color").transform(lambda x: s.issubset(set(x))).astype(int)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use, [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) on `Color` then use `.transform` on column `Plant` to count the number of unique plants associated with the given color, then create a boolean mask `m` where truty values corresponds to condition where the unique plants are greater than 1: Then use [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to select `1` or `0` based on this mask `m`.

```
m = df.groupby('Color')['Plant'].transform('nunique').gt(1)
df['Spillover'] = np.where(m, 1, 0)
```

---

```
df
     Color  Plant  Spillover
0   green1      1          1
1    blue2      1          0
2     red1      1          0
3  purple6      2          1
4    blue2      1          0
5    blue3      2          0
6   green1      2          1
7   green1      1          1
8     red2      1          0
9  purple6      1          1
```